# Class constructor without a body or member initialization?

Tags: c++, c++11

Reading through *The C++ Programming Language, 4th Edition*, there's a class `Circle` inheriting from `Shape` like so

```
class Circle : public Shape {
public:
    Circle(Point p, int rr); // constructor
    Point center() const { return x; }

    void move(Point to) { x=to; }
    void draw() const;
    void rotate(int) {} // nice simple algorithm
private:
    Point x; // center
    int r; // radius
};
```

and the `Shape` class

```
class Shape {
public:
    virtual Point center() const =0; // pure virtual
    virtual void move(Point to) =0;

    virtual void draw() const = 0; // draw on current "Canvas"
    virtual void rotate(int angle) = 0;

    virtual ˜Shape() {} // destructor
// ...
};
```

The part confusing me is `Circle`'s constructor:

`Circle(Point p, int rr);`

Where is the return type? In all previous constructors the return type was specified `void`. I couldn't find a C++ implicit return type (like C's implicit-int rule)

Where is the body/initialization? All previous constructors either initialized via member-list initialization (`:`) or in the function body `{}`. I see neither here and so am wondering how the values are initialized at all.

Comment: oops, sorry. Human error. Could've sworn their old examples did but looking back they don't. Must've mixed it up...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constructors don't specify a return type, and don't return anything.

And it doesn't have a body because it's only the declaration - the definition will be somewhere else, and will look like

```
Circle::Circle (Point p, int rr)
{
 ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense, didn't take into consideration it could've been a declaration.